# How to reload page in the same window?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I made 3 pages - one for Login, one for Register and one for Home. After I press the submit button, I am redirectioned to a new window. I want to be in the same window, but redirectioned to the home page, not a new tab, only one page. After the Login/Register page -> Home page. I have tried location.assign, location.reload, window.location.reload etc., but it did not work. Maybe there is something wrong in my code but I honestly dont know what. HTML and JS code for Login form:

```
<form name="LoginForm">
             <p>Username</p>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter Username">
             <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" onclick="return redirect_home1();">
             <a href="#" onclick="return redirect_resetpassword();">Forgot your password?</a><br>
             <a href="#" onclick="return redirect_register();">Register here for a new account.</a>
         </form>

function redirect_home1() {
   var x = document.forms["LoginForm"]["user"].value;
   var y = document.forms["LoginForm"]["pass"].value;

   if (x == "" && y == "")
      alert("Must complete Username and Password");
   else if (x == "" && y != "")
      alert("Must complete Username");
   else if (y == "" && x != "")
      alert("Must complete Password.");
   else    {  
   alert("Sumbited. You will be redirected in a few seconds...");
   location.assign('location.html');
  }
return true;
}
```

Comment: `location.href = 'location.html'`

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window object to change your page location.

`window.location.href = "filename.html"`